# Kusto - How to trim set of characters before a condition

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm working on Azure App Insights, how do i Trim a string value ?

For Example: I have the customeDimension value for prop_Message as "Question: This is StackOverflow: Yes"

I want to trim everything before Yes and my result set should be "Yes"

Any suggestion?

I tried Trim() and Split(), Trim() requires a set of predefined string to be replaced and Split() just removes everything on the character count. In my case, the character count differs little bit.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
datatable(customDimension:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"prop_Message":"Question: This is StackOverflow: Yes"})
]
| parse customDimension.prop_Message with "Question:" * ":" result
```